# installing Rcpp on R compiled with intel composer on OSX Yosemite

Tags: r, clang, openmp, rcpp, intel-composer

Inspite of succeeding with the compilation of `R-3.1.2` using the intel suite of compilers ver.2015.0.077 including `MKL` on my late 2014 MacBook Pro running Yosemite (outlined [here](http://feng.li/r-with-icc-mkl/)), I am unable to install the excellent `Rcpp` package that I have been thoroughly enjoying thus far via the prepackaged binary `R` for Mavericks. Now, I would like to speed things up a bit, in particular use `OpenMP` that is seemingly incompatible with the default `clang`. I am aware of the `OpenMP/clang` project but it seems that installation on Yosemite is still dodgy.

Apart from several mentions of `Warning in strptime` during `make -j8`, `make install` completes successfully and I am able to install most packages on the freshly compiled `R`. The `Rcpp` package nevertheless fails with:

```
> install.packages("Rcpp")

Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'Asia/Kolkata'
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'GMT'
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'America/New_York'
* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'GMT'
Warning in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) :
  unknown timezone 'America/New_York'
** libs
icpc -I/Users/username/R-3.1.2/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/sw/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O3   -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
In file included from ../inst/include/Rcpp/Vector.h(69),
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h(38),
                 from Date.cpp(31):
../inst/include/Rcpp/vector/swap.h(35): error: "swap" is not a class or function template name in the current scope
  RCPP_GENERATE_SWAP(generic_proxy,VECSXP)
  ^

In file included from ../inst/include/Rcpp/Vector.h(69),
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h(38),
                 from Date.cpp(31):
../inst/include/Rcpp/vector/swap.h(36): error: "swap" is not a class or function template name in the current scope
  RCPP_GENERATE_SWAP(generic_proxy,EXPRSXP)
  ^

In file included from ../inst/include/Rcpp/Vector.h(69),
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h(38),
                 from Date.cpp(31):
../inst/include/Rcpp/vector/swap.h(37): error: "swap" is not a class or function template name in the current scope
  RCPP_GENERATE_SWAP(string_proxy,STRSXP)
  ^

Date.cpp(562): warning #437: reference to local variable of enclosing function is not allowed
              2 * sizeof *sp + 4 * TZ_MAX_TIMES];
                          ^

compilation aborted for Date.cpp (code 2)
make: *** [Date.o] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
```

Is there a way to fix this? Alternatively, how can I switch compilers to be able to invoke 'OpenMP' via `Rcpp` on my MacBook?

Comment: That might be a question for the r-sig-mac mailing list ...

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks again for such a lovely package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my best guess at what's going on. In `Rcpp`, we provide specializations for `std::swap()` [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/vector/swap.h), with relevant bits copied for brevity:

```
namespace std {

#undef RCPP_GENERATE_SWAP
#define RCPP_GENERATE_SWAP(TYPE,RTYPE)                          \
    template<> inline void swap< Rcpp::internal::TYPE<RTYPE> >( \
        Rcpp::internal::TYPE<RTYPE>& a ,                            \
        Rcpp::internal::TYPE<RTYPE>& b) {                           \
            a.swap(b) ;                                             \
        }

RCPP_GENERATE_SWAP(generic_proxy,VECSXP)
RCPP_GENERATE_SWAP(generic_proxy,EXPRSXP)
RCPP_GENERATE_SWAP(string_proxy,STRSXP)
#undef RCPP_GENERATE_SWAP

}
```

It looks like the moment at which your compiler is encountering this header, the appropriate template definition for `std::swap()` has not yet been seen, and so it barfs. This seems surprising to me since we do explicitly provide an `#include <algorithm>` in `RcppCommon.h`, which is included by default. Alternatively, maybe the headers used by your compiler define `std::swap()` in such a way that this form of specialization just doesn't work -- I am not sure.

FWIW, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) advocates providing these specializations within the namespace wherein the types are defined, rather than `std`, to allow for ADL.

You might try modifying the Rcpp sources locally to see if you can provide an alternate way of supporting `std::swap()` (as suggested by `cppreference`), and then proposing an upstream modification to `Rcpp` as well if all seems well.

Comment: Yep. These `swap` might belong in `Rcpp::`

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried installing Rcpp using intel compilers on a linux cluster and Rcpp (as well as RcppArmadillo) installs without complaining. I thus suspect that it's something endemic to Mac OSX, perhaps in conjunction with intel compilers. I will do the suggested and report back.